# css website looks good in Ie8 and FF, but not in Google Chrome

Tags: css

My website looks good in Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox but the part of the picure and top navigation is laso noty in place, can anyone figur out why? For me it's a mystery.

http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but it's definitely to do with the menu `<ul>` or one of its containers. I think you'll just have to wrk your way through... Don't forget Chrome's "Inspect Element" on right-click, it's very useful.

Comment: As a side note, I'd argue that people who use Chrome probably won't need computer help anyways. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `styler.css line #58` from

```
div#wrap_header{font-family: 'trebuchet ms';margin: 0 auto 0 auto;width: 940px;z-index: 2;}
```

to

```
div#wrap_header{font-family: 'trebuchet ms';margin: 0 auto 0 auto;width: 943px;z-index: 2;}
```

Comment: Great, strange that only chrome interpret it like that

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your wrap_header container is not wide enough to fit the tabs, so for some reason chrome thinks it's best to move everything to the next line.

It could very well be a rendering error, and it would be a good idea to report it to the chrome forum.

Comment: Adding just 2px seems to fix it.

Comment: I need 3px on Mac Chrome. 942px is not enough.